# Jackson objectMapper, trying to serialize LocalDate into "yyyy-MM-dd" and LocalTime into "HH:mm:ss"

Tags: java, jackson

So I have an object like this

```
    @EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateBookingDto implements Serializable {
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalTime startTime;
}
```

I am trying to map it to a string and I get it a string like this

```
"{
"date":
{"year":2021,"month":"JANUARY","dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","era":"CE","chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"},"dayOfYear":16,"leapYear":false,"monthValue":1,"dayOfMonth":16},
"startTime":
{"hour":16,"minute":33,"second":13,"nano":721065000}}"
```

How Can I map them to a string in the format "yyyy-mm-dd" for the date and "HH:mm:ss" for the time

How I am mapping the object

```
def objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
def requestBodyJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dtoObject)
```

My pom

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to register the [`JavaTimeModule`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jsr310/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) to your `ObjectMapper`.
This will install a bunch of JSON serializers/deserializers for
classes of the `java.time` package.
(And by the way: in your line 2, use the `ObjectMapper` from line 1,
instead of creating a new one.)

```
def ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
def requestBodyJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dtoObject)
```

Then the JSON output will be like this:

```
{"date":"2021-01-17","startTime":"22:59:15"}
```

Comment: You will need the dependency: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to add additional dependency to your project, you can create a serializer yourself. Annotate your member:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate date;
```

and create the serializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class LocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4746126944463708083L;

    public LocalDateSerializer() {
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        if (value != null) {
            generator.writeString(value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
        }
    }
}
```